# How to work with multiple widgets with single faceted?

Tags: views, search

1) how to get 2 different blocks for the same facet each one has a different widget
We need have block using a collpaisble defined through the custom module and I need select list. I need both of them to use the same facet field.

We have defined the settings in hook_facetapi_default_facet_settings() and we are exporting the fields.

```
 $facet->enabled = TRUE;
 $facet->settings = array(
'weight' => 0,
'widget' => 'collapsible',
'filters' => array(),
'active_sorts' => array(
  'active' => 'active',
  'display' => 'display',
  'count' => 'count',
  'indexed' => 0,
```

Is there a way I can override the realm settings of the block and we can use multiple widgets? Kindly explain me with the example.

2) how can I import the fields to the new solr index throguh custom code/programmatically?